# Question about derivative of an integral

Tags: calculus

One part of my problem is to calculate derivative respect to x of an integral of the form$\int\limits_{0}^{1}{f(y)dy}$. Im not sure is this true $\frac{d}{dx}\left( \int\limits_{0}^{1}{f(y)dy} \right)=0$, since the function is a function of y.

Comment: This is totally true, for sure ! Except if there are typo's. Since the bounds do not depend on $x$ ...

Comment: You're perfectly correct. A definite integral with constant limits is always a pure number and not a function. It's derivative is always zero.

Comment: Almost true, except that folks often write things like $\int_0^1 2xy ~ dy$; this integral is with respect to $y$, and the limits don't involve $y$, and yet the answer is a function of the parameter $x$. Here the function $f$ is $f(y) = 2xy$ which is, of course, also a function of $x$, but sometimes folks don't mention this, esp. when it's something like $f(x) = Cy^2$; a definite integral of this function can be differentiated with respect to $C$, even though in the definition of $f$ "everyone knows" that $C$ is a constant.

Answer (score 0):

Note that while your answer is correct, however your reason "since the function is a function of y" is wrong.

The variable $y$ inside the definite integral is a dummy variable, you could very well replace it with $t$ or $x$ making no difference.

The correct reason is that a definite integral with constant lower and upper limits is a constant, and derivative of a constant wrt any variable is zero.